# WebSocket handshake fails

Tags: javascript, perl, websocket

I have studied RFC 6455 and do not know why the handshake with the 
server fails. I have also observed the communication with the Firefox add-on "HTTP Live Headers" and everything looks fine...

I have tested this in FireFox.

Server/Perl:

```
use IO::Socket::INET; 
use Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1_base64); 

$| = 1;

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort=>6060, Listen=>1, ReuseAddr=>1); 

while(my $client = $sock->accept) {

my $key = undef;
# I connect from localhost to localhost, 
# reading all with one sysread call definitely works in my scenario.
sysread $client, my $buf, 10000;

    while($buf =~s/(.*)\r\n//) {
        my $line = $1; 
        print "line='$line'\n";
        if($line =~/^Sec\-WebSocket\-Key:\s+(.*)$/i) {
            $key = $1; 
         }
     }

     $key .= '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
     my $return_key = sha1_base64($key);
     print $client "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"; 
     print $client "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"; 
     print $client "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
     print $client "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $return_key\r\n"; 
     print $client "\r\n";
}
```

Client/JavaScript

```
if("WebSocket" in window ) {
    sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6060"); 
    sock.onopen = function() { /*this never fires*/ };
    sock.onerror = function() { /*the problem: this always fires*/ };
}
```

Comment: `sock.onerror` takes an `event` parameter, which should have some info about the error.  What's it say?

Comment: I've tried this.sock.onerror= function(err) { alert(err); } gives me "[object Event]", how do I access the object further?

Comment: You should use `console.log`, which will present objects in a much nicer format than alert.

Comment: Chrome tells me that WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:6060/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch 

But I'm creating the key correctly as far as I can see..

Comment: Can you give an example pair of `Sec-WebSocket-Key` and `Sec-WebSocket-Accept`?

Comment: sec-websocket-key: tGrV3F2IqUE9j9OrccYwwQ==
   sec-websocket-key + magic string: tGrV3F2IqUE9j9OrccYwwQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
   sec-websocket-accept: OBMvtVXNqGnOl2C9x3iCf+NAIuA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Perl's `sha1_base64` fails to pad with `=`.  A single `=` at the end will probably work:

```
my $return_key = sha1_base64($key) . "=";
```

Maybe a different sha1/base64 implementation would be better?

Comment: sha1_base64() is broken?

Comment: No, it's not broken. It's explicitly documented: "Note that the base64 encoded string returned is not padded to be
a multiple of 4 bytes long. If you want interoperability with
other base64 encoded sha1 digests you might want to append the
redundant string "=" to the result."

Comment: I didn't call it broken, but it would be accurate.  It claims to do base64 encoding, but does not.  Base64 specifies trailing '=' in certain situations.